# how do i fill in this visor

Tags: modeling

I finished modeling the cast of a daft punk helmet, but how do I go about filling in the visor? Any tips?[image]

The bottom image is what I want the result to be.[image]

Answer (score 1):

i got it, i just made an outline of the top portion and spun around.

Comment: Neat solution :). Don't forget to later mark you answer as accepted ✓, so others can easily find it.